# How to use cmake find_package() with a local copy of the package?

Tags: cmake, zlib, libpng

I'm trying to make a project that has both ZLIB and LIBPNG (and other libraries).  LibPNG's CMakeLists.txt file has this in it:  `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)` It's stock code that comes with it and I don't want to change it.

I'm building on Windows (Visual Studio).  This is a cross-platform application (Windows, Mac, Linux and Mobile devices) I cannot rely on /usr/lib versions of any libraries.  So I'm building them all with my project together.

I can't get LibPNG to build unless I hack this up.  In an upper-level CMakeLists.txt file, I put this in there:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(contrib/${CUSTOM_ZLIB_LOCATION})
SET(ZLIB_FOUND ON CACHE BOOL "Yes")
SET(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/contrib/${CUSTOM_ZLIB_LOCATION} {CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/${CUSTOM_ZLIB_LOCATION})
SET(ZLIB_LIBRARY zlib CACHE STRING "zlib library name")
```

This satisfies `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)`  But I think this is a hack.  Is there some straight forward way to build the local copy of zlib without all the 3 extra lines?

Comment: Yes. Didn't do anything for me.  Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: I use the same approach as you for building zlib/libpng in one of my projects and no issues so far. Two minor nitpicks: You should turn the `set` for `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` into a `set(... CACHE STRING "")` as well. Also, setting `ZLIB_FOUND` manually is not necessary. With both `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` and `ZLIB_LIBRARY` are set in the cache, the find script should just work as expected. Consider linking both libs statically to minimize potential conflicts with system libraries.

Answer (score 9):

I only added this line at the beginning (at least before `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)`) and it worked for me.

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT <zlib folder here>)
```

But others may need doing something like:

```
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12 OR CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 3.12)
  # Enable find_package uses of <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
endif()

set(ZLIB_ROOT <zlib folder here>)
```

> We set the policy to `NEW`.
> The `OLD` behavior for this policy is to ignore `<PackageName>_ROOT` variables.
>
> CMake version 3.22.1 warns when the policy is not set (and defaults to `OLD` behavior).